# Объясните почему функция вывела такой результат?

Tags: javascript

```js
function sayHi() {   // (1)
  alert( "Привет" );
}

var func = sayHi;    // (2)
   


alert(func())
```

создаем функцию sayHi, передаем код функции в переменную func и через alert выводим должно в func  вывести 'привет',  выводит undefined можно предположить что в первом alerte нет return, вставим все равно undefined почему ?

Comment: почитайте про hoisting/всплытие.

Comment: А какой результат вы, собственно, ожидали получить?

Comment: @ Yaant я же написал же что код в моем понимании должен вывести в func привет

Comment: Так он и выводит, в первом alert'е.

Comment: @Yaant  Я передаю в переменную  func  код функции sayHi; во втором alerte я вызываю эту функцию по идем мне должно 2 раз вывести  'привет', но возвращает undefined предпологаю что в перед первом alerte я не добавил return добавляю его все равно выводит undefined ПОЧЕМУ !!!!

Comment: @Yaant учись у Sonic Myst

Comment: Учиться чему именно? :)

Comment: Yaant для начало прочитать инфу под кодом а потом писать свой коммент

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все потому что, при alert(func()) проиходит сначала вызов func() далее в теле этой функции вызывается alert( "Привет" ), но далее она(func()) ничего не возвращает, т. е. это эквивалентно alert(undefined).

Если хотите чтобы func чтото возвращала, то нужно было делать так:

```
function sayHi() {   // (1)
  alert( "Привет" ); //return alert( "Привет" ) - результат бы не изменился.
  return "text";
}

var func = sayHi;    // (2)
alert(func())
```

Comment: Sonic Myst понял, спасибо забыл что alert выводит но ничего не возвращает или возращает undefined

Comment: @xes, тут стоит пояснить, что если даже alert возвращал бы что-то, то все равно результат был бы такой же, все потому что нет в теле func перед alert нет ключевого слова return.

Comment: правильно я думаю если функция разновидность объекта то в переменную мы присваиваем не саму функцию а ссылку на функцию ?

Comment: Подробнее можно посмотреть https://learn.javascript.ru/function-declaration-expression